# Primefaces, p:fileDownload ajax="false" nullPointerException

Tags: java, primefaces

Olá, sou novo aqui, já procurei pelo Google da vida e aqui no Stack algo semelhante mas não encontrei. Não sou tão experiente como DEV então quem puder ajudar...

O problema consiste no `p:DownloadFile`. Pelo menos eu creio ser ali. Dá um erro 500 de nullpointerException e o log aparentemente não diz nada.
Uso o framework primefaces.
No xhtml tenho o datatable e a column do botão:

```
    <p:dataTable value="#{lancamentoRCCadastroMB.arquivos}" var="arquivo" styleClass="small"   
                                scrollable="true"  scrollHeight="150" id="gridNotaFiscalDigiRC"
                                emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado."
                                rowSelectMode="click" rowHover="true">

            <p:column headerText="Arquivo" styleClass="align-center" >
                    <p:commandButton id="btnDownload2RC" ajax="false" actionListener="#{lancamentoRCCadastroMB.downloadAnexoLancamento(arquivo.codigo)}"
                                            icon="fa fa-download state-primary" title="Download" value="#{arquivo.nome}"
                                            styleClass="rowClick" immediate="true" process="gridNotaFiscalDigiRC" rendered="#{lancamentoRCCadastroMB.analistaOrcamentario}">
                        <p:fileDownload value="#{lancamentoRCCadastroMB.streamedContentAnexoLancamento}" />                     
                    </p:commandButton>              
            </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

No bean:

```
public void downloadAnexoLancamento(Integer pCodigo) {

    ArquivoLancamentoVO lArquivo = new ArquivoLancamentoVO();
    if(arquivos != null && !arquivos.isEmpty()) {

        for(ArquivoLancamentoVO lArquivoLoop : arquivos) {
            if(pCodigo.equals(lArquivoLoop.getCodigo())) {
                lArquivo = lArquivoLoop;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(lArquivo.getCodigo() != null) {
            ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(lArquivo.getArquivo());
            streamedContentAnexoLancamento = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/x-download", lArquivo.getNome());
        }           
    }
}
```

Acontece que ao clicar no botão `id="btnDownload2RC"`, deveria chamar o método do bean downloadAnexoLancamento e preparar o arquivo para download. Debugando o método não é invocado quando o `ajax="false"`. Se coloco para true ele chega a chamar o método mas não realiza o download do arquivo.
Já ouvi dizer que esses processos e updates do prime podem estar me atrapalhando, mas já verifiquei o código e não encontro a falha.

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser que o listener esteja sendo chamado após executar o `getStreamedContentAnexoLancamento()`, portando não crie o streamed content. Tenta fazer essas modificações:

No XHTML:

```
<p:commandButton
    id="btnDownload2RC"
    icon="fa fa-download state-primary"
    title="Download"
    value="#{arquivo.nome}"
    ajax="false"
    styleClass="rowClick"
    immediate="true"
    process="gridNotaFiscalDigiRC"
    rendered="#{lancamentoRCCadastroMB.analistaOrcamentario}"
    >
    <p:fileDownload value="#{lancamentoRCCadastroMB.downloadAnexoLancamento(arquivo.codigo)}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

No Bean:

```
public StreamedContent downloadAnexoLancamento(Integer pCodigo) {

    ArquivoLancamentoVO lArquivo = new ArquivoLancamentoVO();

    if(arquivos != null && !arquivos.isEmpty()) {

        for (ArquivoLancamentoVO lArquivoLoop : arquivos) {
            if(pCodigo.equals(lArquivoLoop.getCodigo())) {
                lArquivo = lArquivoLoop;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(lArquivo.getCodigo() != null) {
            ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(lArquivo.getArquivo());
            streamedContentAnexoLancamento = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/x-download", lArquivo.getNome());
        }           
    }

    return streamedContentAnexoLancamento;
}
```